# Store Git ID in variable in batch script

Tags: git, batch-file

I am working with jenkins and git. I want to get difference between current commit and the commit before current. I want to make this current and previous commit id;s to be generated at runtime.
 I am using this in batch file but it is not executing the git rev-parse commands and storing the hash id in prev_com and curr_com. Any help is appreciated.

```
cd "C:\Users\TF255014\Eclipse Projects Repo\Hello World"
set prev_com=${git rev-parse @~}
set curr_com=${git rev-parse HEAD}
echo %prev_com%
git diff %prev_com% %curr_com%
```

Comment: You cannot assign the output of a command to a variable with the set statement like you can in BASH.  Open up a cmd prompt and type: `set /?`.  You will not see any syntax to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you are mixing `bash` and `batch` scrips. If you are on Windows, you can assign the output of a command to a variable using 'temporary' files:

```sh
git rev-parse @~ > prev_com.txt
set /p prev_com=<prev_com.txt
git rev-parse HEAD > curr_com.txt
set /p curr_com=<curr_com.txt
```

or for loops:

```sh
for /f %%i in ('git rev-parse @~')   do set prev_com=%%i
for /f %%i in ('git rev-parse HEAD') do set curr_com=%%i
```

The following would work in a `bash` script:

```
prev_com=$(git rev-parse @~)
```

---

Apart from that, I don't think you need the two variables. You could simply run:

```
git show HEAD
```

or, to get the diff only:

```
git show --pretty= HEAD
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am new to batch scripting so confusing the syntax  with bash scripting. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone bumps on this thread...

following is a one liner for BAT:

```
for /f %%i in ('git.exe rev-parse @~') do set COMMIT_ID=%%i
```